# keras custom loss function call hidden layer dense operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to define a custom loss function in keras that uses an intermediary layer output, manipulate it (let's say multiply by 2( and then and back into the model to produce the final output. So assuming a model

```
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
encoding_dim = 14


#encoder
input_tensor = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))

encoderOut = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="tanh", 
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_tensor)
encoderOut = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation="relu")(encoderOut)

encoder = Model(input_tensor, encoderOut)


#decoder
decoder_input = Input(shape=(int(encoding_dim / 2),))
decoderOut = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation='tanh',name='decoder_input')(decoder_input)
decoderOut = Dense(input_dim, activation='relu',name='decoder_output')(decoderOut)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoderOut)

#autoencoder
autoInput = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))
encoderOut = encoder(autoInput)
decoderOut = decoder(encoderOut)
autoencoder = Model(inputs=autoInput, outputs=decoderOut)
```

My loss function is

```
def L2Loss(y_true,y_pred):
    get_layer_output_enc = K.function([encoder.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [encoder.layers[2].output])
    out= get_layer_output_enc([y_true])[0]*10
```

Unfortunately when I run it I got:

```
    517             None, None,
    518             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 519             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    520     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    521     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'model_89_target_28' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[Node: model_89_target_28 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Alternatively I tried to reproduce a dense layer operation extracting the weights:

```
    layer_output_enc = encoder.layers[2].output#get_layer_output_enc([y_true])[0]*10
    w_dec0 = decoder.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
    b_dec0 = decoder.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
    print type(layer_output_enc),'--',layer_output_enc.shape
    layer_output_enc = backend.cast(layer_output_enc,'float64')#tf.convert_to_tensor(layer_output_enc)
    out_dec0 = K.dot(layer_output_enc,w_dec0)+b_dec0
    print out_dec0.shape
    out2 = K.tanh(out_dec0)
```

But again I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

which is weird because I now 'layer_output_enc' is of type :  
Any help appreciated.

Comment: here a simple solution to put intermediate layers in loss computation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454500/how-to-use-tensorflow-custom-loss-for-a-keras-model

Answer (score 2):

You can't call your model within the loss function of Keras model, you can only use the input tensors `y_true` and `y_pred`. So the loss function cannot access intermediate layers. I had the same need and the tricky solution I found was to concatenate the output tensor with the intermediate layer as a new output of the model. It may be much simpler working directly with tensorflow though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about using the weights? In that case it should be a way to replicate a dense layer operation? Have a  look at my edited question

Comment: What are the input/output of your net and what do you want the loss to be?

Comment: Input an array, output another array. The loss should take the encoder layer of the last y_pred, multiply it  by a factor then, apply the decoder. This new y_pred_fac will be used to calculate the mean square error loss. So the problem is to access the actual last weight value of each layer and use them.

Comment: "access the actual last weight value" - as far as i know, this isn't possible in Keras loss function. "multiply it by a factor" - a constant?   "mean square error loss" -  of y_pred_fac  and y_pred or y_true?

Comment: is it impossible? how about this w_dec0 = decoder.layers[1].get_weights()[0]? Does not work inside at loss function?

Comment: It won't work since your loss function is being called once during compilation. During training, the actual loss is computed with tensors operations.